# is the .ksh deleting path slashes?

Tags: ksh, processbuilder, backslash

Under a Windows 7 env, I have a java code that launches a .ksh script. The latter takes a path to a directory as an argument and has to create a new folder in it.

The Java code:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = create(this.shell);
    pb.command().add(commandLine);
```

`this.shell` is set to `{"cmd.exe", "/C"}`
 while commandLine is:

```
""C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\Appxxx\..\Scripts\Mod\Launch.ksh" "C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\Appxxx\dir\"
```

the process is launched with:

```
pb.start()
```

the *.ksh* should create a folder "*log*" into *Appxxx\dir*

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/log': No such file or directory
C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\Appxxx\Scripts\Mod\Launch.ksh[38]: can't create /log/UCS.log: No such file or directory
```

Even if the path clearly exists. So, I tried to launch the same command (without quotes) directly on the cygwin terminal and I got the following log:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘C:UsersAndreaDesktopAppxxxdir 

C:UsersAndreaDesktopAppxxx/log’: No such file or directory
C:/Users/Andrea/Desktop/Appxxx/Scripts/Mod/Launch.ksh[38]: can't create C:UsersAndreaDesktopAppxxxdir C:UsersAndreaDesktopAppxxx/log/UCS.log: No such file or directory
```

To me, it's clear something deletes all the slashes and so the path cannot be found.
As attempt, on the cygwin terminal I tried to launch the same line but changing every / with a . **It works!**
Unfortunately, when I tried to do that for the `commandLine` in Java, it failed as well.

Hints?

P.S.: I am not allowed to change the java code and the ksh neither. Finally, the application is guaranteed to work on a Linux os.

Thanks you all

Comment: the error message 'can't create /log/UCS.log` indicates whatever env-var preceding `/log/...` is empty. Can't tell you why that is happening, but in *nix land, you need to `export myVAR` to indicate that the variable should be visible to all sub-processes created from that level down. The error message `can't create C:UsersAndreaDesktop...`. indicates that the `ksh` is processing the Windows path, and stripping out the path separators (`\\`) because ksh sees the `\\` char as an escape char. This can be avoided by surrounding the path value in dbl-quotes, i.e. `"C:\Users\Andread\Desktop\..."`.

Comment: If you are dealing with multiple layers of variable scanning, you may need to add extra layers of dbl-quotes so each layer strips off one set, but ultimately leaves a dbl-quoted string to be processed by the `ksh` script. It would help if you can add the `mkdir` line from the `ksh` script to your Q. If the variable there is not quoted, then this can't be fixed (If I understand the problem correctly) ;-) . Good luck.!

Comment: I think the preceding of /log/... is correctly parsed since in the script there is:

if [ ! -d "$1/toolkit_rep/log" ]
then
 mkdir "$1/toolkit_rep/log"
fi

and if I try to echo $1, on cygwin I see the correct path.

Comment: I'd have to disagree. You'e saying (in effect) that the error message is wrong. Based on the error message you've included, the `mkdir` command only received `/log/USC.log` as it's argument. It went to the root dir `/`, and couldn't find a `./log` directory. Why the `$1/toolkit_rep` part is missing is another matter. Good luck! ;-)!